# KnockoutJS template doesn't work in IE8, gives binding error

Tags: internet-explorer-8, knockout.js

I've got the following KnockoutJS 2.0 code that works fine in all modern browsers, but fails on IE8.

Here's the simplified code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td data-bind="template: { foreach: fooItems, name: 'foo-template' }></td>
       <td data-bind="template: { foreach: barItems, name: 'foo-template' }></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script id="foo-template" type="text/html">
   <div data-bind="click: SomeMethod">
       foobar
   </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var viewModel = {
       fooItems: ko.observableArray(),
       barItems: ko.observableArray(),
   }
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

This works fine on IE9, Chrome, Firefox.

However, on IE8, I get the following error:

> "Unable to parse bindings. SomeMethod is undefined."

Debugging this in IE8, I see the following information:

[image]

It's about to throw the exception, and it's coming during the rendering of the foo-template.

**Notice that $data is undefined.** That's why SomeMethod is not resolving; it should exist on $data.SomeMethod, but $data is undefined.

Why is this failing on IE8?

Comment: The JsFiddle below worked for me as well. Maybe the simplified version is missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and was quite disapointed to see that you solved your issue without knowing how.

So, for the futur visitors, here is how I solved this :

I had initialised the array used in a foreach with an hard-coded array, ending with a trailing coma.

In your example, that would looks like this :

```
viewModel.fooItems([
    {SomeMethod: function () {}},
    {SomeMethod: function () {}},   // <- here is the evil coma
]);
```

When looking a little closer, ie8 evaluated this array as a 3 items array whose last item was undefined. Hence the undefined $data.

Of course, having the same symptoms doesn't mean your problem was the same, but if it can help anybody ...

Comment: Thanks for helping out with this issue, Thomas. I'm marking yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your exampel in jsfiddle with IE8, no problem

http://jsfiddle.net/mFLDv/

Comment: Huh. Ok. So the simplified version is missing something. Ok. I'll try removing some pieces until I can isolate the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I moved around some code and magically it started working. I suspect I stumbled on a very niche bug in KnockoutJS, but without knowing what exactly fixed it, it's hard to say. Thanks for answering with the fiddle, that led me to futzing with the code, which eventually solved the problem. Marking as answer.